# Spark: Can I get the case class from a data set?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm converting a data frame to a data set using:

```
val dataSet = dataFrame.as[CustomClass]
```

How can I get what case class this dataSet is based on? I tried `dataSet.schema` but that prints the entire schema. I want it to print `CustomClass`

The Application that's calling this method will only get the returned dataSet and it would be nice for them to know what case class it belongs to

Comment: Can you give more context for this? In the example you provide, you already know the class and don't need to figure it out.

Comment: I do know it. But the Application that's calling this method will only get the returned dataSet and it would be nice for them to know what case class it belongs to.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what that code looks like? If you know the type, you can just encode it in the return type of the method. Can the method potentially return different types, or will it always be the same `CustomClass`?

Answer (score 0):

A (simple) solution that works in limited scenarios:
If you have at least one element in the `dataSet` then you can do `dataSet.take(1)(0).getClass.getName`.